# Примеси.Разбор кода примеси(миксина)

Tags: javascript, prototype, mixins

Написано,что статья про примеси для чайников.Видимо я под эту категорию людей  не попадаю.Потому что многое в работе данного метода для "подмешивания" в прототипы объектов -не ясно. Ниже сам код примеси.не понятно почему  в 
 строке 1  в переменную аргументы прототипа начиная именно с единицы?Зачем перебирать  объект сначала в цикле for, а потом в  вложенном цикле for in.

```js
function extend_2(object)
{
    var mixins = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1); // (1)
    for (var i = 0; i < mixins.length; ++i)
    {
        for (var prop in mixins[i]) //(2)
        {
            if (typeof object.prototype[prop] === "undefined")
            {
                bindMethod = function (mixin, prop) 
                {
                    return function () { mixin[prop].apply(this, arguments) }
                }

                object.prototype[prop] = bindMethod(mixins[i], prop);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _почему в строке 1 в переменную аргументы прототипа начиная именно с единицы?_ - потому что нулевой параметр - это объект куда добавляются

Comment: _Зачем перебирать объект сначала в цикле for, а потом в вложенном цикле for in._ - если присмотришься - идет разный перебор разных объектов